# DataPrep eda plot(df) on VSCodium(Code) jupyterlab only shows in half the screen

Tags: exploratory-data-analysis

I'm trying to use DataPrep.eda's plot function on a .ipynb file in VSCodium using Jupyterlab.

However when I run the function, I can only see half the plots because the whole container has moved to the right.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UH7YQ.png

How do I shift it back to the left?